# Run a function when a new site is created in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite

I am currently developing a multi-site plug-in for WordPress. I need to run a function when a new site is created.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are looking for an action/filter.

`wpmu_new_blog` this action is fired in `wpmu_create_blog` function (wp-includes/ms-functions.php)

```
do_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', $blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta );
```

Comment: I need to run my custom function when a new site is created

Comment: I need to teach you how to hook action?

Comment: if possible can u ?

Comment: Actions and filters are the fundamental knowledge of wordpress plugin development. Hooking an action is the most basic stuff. If you have no idea what they idea, I would suggest googling about add_action first.

Answer (score 3):

Since WP 5.1.0, `wpmu_new_blog` has been deprecated in favour of `wp_insert_site`:

```php
/**
 * Fires once a site has been inserted into the database.
 *
 * @since 5.1.0
 *
 * @param WP_Site $new_site New site object.
 */
do_action( 'wp_insert_site', $new_site );
```

Use it like this in your plugin or theme:

```php
add_action('wp_insert_site', function($site) {
  // do something
});
```

A good place to look for available hooks is `wp-includes/ms-default-filters.php`

[wp_insert_site on WordPress Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_site/)